# Received RSSI and dbm filtering with kalman-filter in javascript

Tags: javascript, wifi, kalman-filter, rssi

I would like to filter our received RSSI signal to a more accurate signal. We did a lot of research to the "kalman filter". But our results seems to be the average of all our RSSI signals. Is it possible we have to decide the "measurement noise" and "process noise" manually? Else I think I do not understand the workprocess of the kalman-filter.

Any help? Can someone explain how to make use of it? Especially in our case, trying to position someone's smartphone in a given room. So the noise has to be reduced to get the right distance out of the RSSI.

Answer (score 1):

It might be late but this is what I found 
[Kalman filters explained: Removing noise from RSSI signals](https://wouterbulten.nl/blog/tech/kalman-filters-explained-removing-noise-from-rssi-signals/)